# Listar em Mysql tabelas que não tenham AVG

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas tabelas em MySQL assim:

LOCAL

```
id | nome
```

NOTA_LOCAL (notas dadas pelos usários para cada local)

```
id | id_local | nota
```

Estou listando os locais e já mostrando a média de notas que cada local recebe, assim:

```
SELECT *, AVG(local_nota.nota) AS 'nota' FROM local
LEFT JOIN local_nota ON local.id = local_nota.id_local
GROUP BY local_nota.id_local
ORDER BY local.nome ASC
```

Os locais que possuem notas ele lista, mas não lista os locais que ainda não receberam notas, o que mudar no código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava no GRUP BY, alterei para agrupar ao id do LOCAL, assim:

```
SELECT *, AVG(local_nota.nota) AS 'nota' FROM local
LEFT JOIN local_nota ON local.id = local_nota.id_local
GROUP BY local.id
ORDER BY local.nome ASC
```

Comment: Seria bom marcar como aceita sua solução para que o post não fique indefinidamente em aberto

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer desta forma

```
SELECT local.nome, AVG(nota_local.nota) AS nota FROM local LEFT JOIN nota_local ON local.id = nota_local.id_local GROUP BY local.nome ORDER BY local.nome
```

Comment: Oi, não entendi a diferença entre o meu código e o seu, são iguais... só mudou alguns detalhes que não surtiram mudanças.